# Character encoding works on one page, but not the other

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding

I have a page `http://199.193.248.80/test/test.php` that contains the « character.

But when I read this page with js on `http://199.193.248.80/test/test.html`, the character turns into �

Both pages are using Charset Windows-1252 so I have no idea why it works on one page but not the other. What needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: If you open both files with a text editor, do both files have same character encoding defined?

Comment: Add <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> on your html page

Comment: @swapnesh That did not do anything

Comment: @Sasquiha it does work in chrome, but not in any other browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because PHP sets a different character set (when serving the `.php`) in the headers than Apache does (when serving the `.html`). Browsers use the character set that's mentioned in the response headers; it overrides the `<meta>` tags in fact.

By default PHP chooses `iso-8859-1` I believe, but you can override the character set in PHP by using:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252');
```

Or change the `php.ini` for a global change.

See also:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset (for Apache)
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset (for PHP)

Comment: interesting.. what do you suggest setting in the php file?

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` where UTF-8 is your desired charset

Comment: @KevinDuke your .php is not the problem, it's Apache you should be looking at if I understand your question correctly; or rather, both character sets should be the same

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use the HTML-entity form: `&laquo;`

This way it doesn't matter what charset you use for your file, because your browser just parses it.

In PHP you can use `$str = htmlentities( $str );` to encode a string

Comment: This will not work because there will be other characters besides the one I provided which will break. I don't want to convert every unicode character to an html-entity either, there should be a clear explanation why it's not working

Comment: I quote: "What needs to be done to fix this?". I have provide a solution. There could be millions of reasons why it doesn't work for you. It could be your browser, your OS or the server. You should use the html-entities in first place.

Comment: this does provide a solution but not the cleanest. I have several documents that aren't just 1 line strings with many print statements. I'm looking for a solution that would effect the entire document for speed optimizations.